# Unable to install openAI-gym on python for windows

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

it's giving me an error when I'm trying to pip install gym,
please help
I'm installing on my windows 7

This is the Error:

```
spyder 3.3.2 requires pyqt5<5.10; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\cloudpickle-0.6.1.dist-info\\installer'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Full Excerpt Follows:

`!pip install gym`

````
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/38/87aefd5388f6062267384b7e8f97dbc27c54b3e6137a5148b43d5c10890c/gym-0.13.1.tar.gz (1.6MB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.12.0)
Collecting pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0 (from gym)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/fc/dad5eaaab68f0c21e2f906a94ddb98175662cc5a654eee404d59554ce0fa/pyglet-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0MB)
Collecting cloudpickle~=1.2.0 (from gym)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/f4/4a080c349c1680a2086196fcf0286a65931708156f39568ed7051e42ff6a/cloudpickle-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym) (0.17.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: gym
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gym: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gym: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\95\14\8e\b4f5c72600f654312b40c0844d4c23f146f291c48ac7a5df62
Successfully built gym
Installing collected packages: pyglet, cloudpickle, gym
  Found existing installation: pyglet 1.4.1
    Uninstalling pyglet-1.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pyglet-1.4.1
  Found existing installation: cloudpickle 0.6.1
    Uninstalling cloudpickle-0.6.1:
spyder 3.3.2 requires pyqt5<5.10; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\cloudpickle-0.6.1.dist-info\\installer'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.```
````

Comment: Try running from an Administrative Command Prompt, it is having trouble accessing the packages under your Aanaconda directory.  If you are not logged in as an admin on the system also do that.

Comment: Also make sure you are on the correct version of Python, the script says that one of the components needs Python Version Greater than or equal to 3 and that it was not found.

Comment: @BenPersonick thanks bro for your help, it worked when I opened command prompt as an admin

Comment: Glad to help, I'll post the above as an answer to the Q to make sure others with the problem get to se the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues reported:

```
 spyder 3.3.2 requires pyqt5<5.10; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site- packages\\cloudpickle-0.6.1.dist-info\\installer'
 Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

1) Access Denied:  It is having trouble accessing the packages under your Aanaconda directory.

**Try running from an Administrative Command Prompt,  If you are not logged in as an admin on the system also do that.**

2) Python Version:  The script says that one of the components needs Python Version Greater than or equal to 3 and that it was not found

**Make sure you are on the correct version of Python.**